# Does caching in spark streaming increase performance

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

So i'm preforming multiple operations on the same rdd in a kafka stream. Is caching that RDD going to improve performance?

Comment: Another useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37701793/2213164

Answer (score 4):

When running multiple operations on the same dstream, `cache` will substantially improve performance. This can be observed on the Spark UI:

Without the use of `cache`, each iteration on the dstream will take the same time, so the total time to process the data in each batch interval will be linear to the number of iterations on the data:
[image: Spark Streaming no cache]

When `cache` is used, the first time the transformation pipeline on the RDD is executed, the RDD will be cached and every subsequent iteration on that RDD will only take a fraction of the time to execute.

(In this screenshot, the execution time of that same job was further reduced from 3s to 0.4s by reducing the number of partitions)
 [image: Spark Streaming with cache]

Instead of using `dstream.cache` I would recommend to use `dstream.foreachRDD` or `dstream.transform` to gain direct access to the underlying RDD and apply the `persist` operation.  We use matching `persist` and `unpersist` around the iterative code to clean up memory as soon as possible:

```
dstream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  rdd.cache()
  col.foreach{id => rdd.filter(elem => elem.id == id).map(...).saveAs...}
  rdd.unpersist(true)
}
```

Otherwise, one needs to wait for the time configured on `spark.cleaner.ttl` to clear up the memory.

Note that the default value for `spark.cleaner.ttl` is infinite, which is not recommended for a production 24x7 Spark Streaming job.

Comment: 2 questions: 
1. is Kafa rdd really in memory or it's just the offset of the records which will only be retrieved upon actions. If this is the case, then that's why cache improve performance.
2. looks the dstream is not the original kafka rdd as the records has id attribute in your code. The original kafka rdd is (String, String) tuple. If this is the case, then cache will save the intermediate transformation, which will also improve the performance.
The final improvement is probably from both

Comment: @user3931226 it would be better to turn that into a new question for the benefit of the whole community.

Answer (score 1):

> Spark also supports pulling data sets into a cluster-wide in-memory
>   cache. This is very useful when data is accessed repeatedly, such as
>   when querying a small “hot” dataset or when running an iterative
>   algorithm like PageRank.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching

Comment: Yes but are there any benefits of doing this in a streaming job aka with dstreams that are already in memory?

Comment: caching is useful if the data in the DStream will be computed multiple times (e.g., multiple operations on the same data). For window-based operations like reduceByWindow and reduceByKeyAndWindow and state-based operations like updateStateByKey, this is implicitly true.